# Parsing String to Calendar in Java?

Tags: java, android, exception

I am having trouble parsing a string to a calendar object in java by pulling it from an XML element (I'm writing an android app) so I can calculate the length of time between the time in the string and the current time. I am brand new to java and come from the .NET world, so any additional background here can be really helpful.

The code I am trying to use is:

```
// Using this class to define the format for date parsing.
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

// readArrivalValue reads the element from XML, which seems to be working.
String prdt = readArrivalValue(parser, "prdt");
// At this point prdt evaluates to the correct value: "20150331 20:14:40"

Date datePRDT = sdf.parse(prdt);
// datePRDT doesn't seem to be set properly. It evaluates to:
//    datePRDT = {java.util.Date@830031077456}"Sat Jan 31 20:14:40 CST 2015"
//      milliseconds = 1422761216000

// element.prdt is of type Calendar. Nothing is done to this prior to this statement.
element.prdt.setTime(datePRDT); // This throws a null pointer exception
```

Comment: what is `element.prdt`?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that - Calendar. I'll edit the post. And now I'm realizing I probably have to initialize that in some way, as it might be a reference type?

Comment: I am guessing that datePRDT is not causing the NPE but either `element` or `element.prdt` object is causing it. Make sure you initialized them

Comment: That makes sense, as it's not initialized. Is it best practice to use Calendar.getInstance() in this case to initialize, or just new GregorianCalendar() ? And why is my parse coming back with the wrong value?

Comment: I would recommend using the `getInstance` that it will directly use the date of the system where you are running it.

Comment: Got it, thank you, that solved the null reference exception, however, the month is still getting set to January instead of March. The rest of the pieces of the timestamp are getting set properly. Edit: Because mm is minutes and MM should be month, so my formatter should read yyyyMMdd, not yyyymmdd. Thanks everyone!

Comment: It is because `mm` stands for `Minute in hour` not the month instead use the `MM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues with your code:

- Fix your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern as you're parsing minutes `mm` in place of months `MM` too!

  ```
  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                            ^
  ```
- You most likely forgot to initialize your `Calendar` instance and hence get an NPE.

  ```
  element.prdt = Calendar.getInstance();
  element.prdt.setTime(datePRDT);
  ```